# Python: Django - vs code debugger error in manage.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Problem: VS Code debugger in manage.py, these code is generated when you start a new project in django

**EDIT**

Actual Error:

`user@user:~/PROJ/py/lib$ cd /home/user/PROJ/py/lib ; env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" python /home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.3.1/pythonFiles/PythonTools/visualstudio_py_launcher.py /home/user/PROJ/py/lib 42135 34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14 RedirectOutput,RedirectOutput,DjangoDebugging /home/user/PROJ/py/lib/manage.py runserver --noreload --nothreading
  File "/home/user/PROJ/py/lib/manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "lib.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Here's my config in launch.json:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Django",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
    "args": [
        "runserver",
        "--noreload",
        "--nothreading"
    ],
    "debugOptions": [
        "RedirectOutput",
        "Django",
    ]
}
```

Comment: Post full traceback please. Are you sure you are running this with Python 3.x?

Comment: Remove `from exc` after `)` closing parentheses

Comment: @Selcuk yes I'm using python 3.x

Comment: From the error it looks a lot like the file is being executed using Python 2. The `raise .. from` syntax is only valid in Python 3.x. You could put `print(sys.version)` at the top of manage.py to check this. You'll first have to get rid of the offending ` from exc` in order for the file to execute at all.

Comment: @DBrowne `3.6.3 (default, Oct  6 2017, 08:44:35)` pretty sure its python 3.

Comment: You have probably both Python 2.x and 3.x installed. See [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) to configure the correct one for VS Code.

Comment: @Selcuk the documentation helps a lot, forgot to set the correct environment. thanks